# Uncaught TypeErrors have me baffled

Tags: 8, javascript

This is my first Drupal 8 site but I have been building Drupal sites since Drupal 6. I am getting lots of Uncaught TypeErrors in the JavaScript console that I can't figure out. I have spend hours searching and have not found an answer. What am I missing?

> [image: Errors]

I am developing a custom theme. The site is on Mamp. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I think I am narrowing down the problem. I started a new theme from the start and am copying files from the current theme and when I copied the page.html.twig file the JavaScript errors appeared. I just have to find what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. I believe the page.html.twig file I was using had a hidden character that was causing problems. I am using the same code in a new theme and everything is fine, but I had to type the code again instead of copying it. When I copied it, the errors returned. It helped to test each block of code at a time with code that I knew worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all js variables are missing, that are in:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{...}</script>
```

This json array is on every page drupal delivers. You can check this on a fresh drupal install.

There can be a problem with your theme, probably with the html template.

Comment: If I switch to a core theme, the errors go away. What should I look for? Should I be looking in html.html.twig or THEMENAME.libraries.yml?

Comment: I checked the page source and the js variables appear to be loaded. The custom theme prints the
`<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{...}</script>`

Comment: First check if the json array is in the html, if not check the html.html.twig. Second check if drupalSettingsLoader.js is loaded, if not check the dependencies in *.libraries.yml, look for core/drupal or core/drupalSettings.